# Google Cloud Platform and (uneditable) Unlimited Daily spending limit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Platform -> App Engine -> Settings -> Application Settings

The "Daily Spending Limit" shows Unlimited. I do not want an unlimited Daily Spending Limit.

I clicked the Edit button above it. It just says Daily Spending and USD.

How do I edit the Daily Spending limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just enter an amount next to the USD and save it, so that you can have [control over your application costs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Billable_Resource_Quotas).

Comment: Also a reminder that GAE Flex, and custom runtimes are not limited by spending limits and require budget alerts to monitor usage.